# fixed by workaround: c++ : boost_log : how does compiler choose st or mt

Tags: c++, boost

My env: solaris 5.10  gcc 4.8.2  boost 1.54

Codes:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>


int main() {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "init " << filename << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles options and issue:

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ x.cc -lboost_log -lsocket  -lnsl -o x
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
 boost::log::v2s_st::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_st::record&) /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::aux::unhandled_exception_count()  /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_st::record_view::public_data const*) /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_st::attribute_set const&) /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::trivial::logger::get() /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::core::get_logging_enabled() const /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_st::record&) /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_st::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*) /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 boost::log::v2s_st::sources::aux::get_severity_level() /var/tmp//ccPKqK2f.o
 ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to x
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but

```
-bash-3.2$ nm -A /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so | grep unhandled_exception_count
/usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so: [2277]  |              735336|                  24|FUNC |GLOB |0    |10     |_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix3aux25unhandled_exception_countEv
```

We can see there is `boost::log::v2s_**mt**::aux::unhandled_exception_count, but hasn't boost::log::v2s_st::aux::unhandled_exception_count`.

My question is how compiler choose which one to use in this sistuation?

I have read http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html. 
but still unknown what does **"no threading support"** means.  trid to compile with -lpthread, but got the same error.

#### update

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ x.cc  -lsocket  -lnsl -o x -pthread -lboost_log
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&) /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
icu::Collator::createInstance(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()   /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
icu::Locale::Locale(icu::Locale const&) /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*) /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
icu::Locale::Locale()               /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
icu::Locale::~Locale()              /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*) /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()  /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get() /var/tmp//ccZHBWis.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to x
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

with the *pthread* flag, it starts to use "mt",  but it is asking for v2s_mt_posix.  but our library provided *v2s_mt_posix3*

#### Workaround

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ x.cc  -lsocket  -lnsl -o x -pthread /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.a  /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a -lrt
-bash-3.2$ ./x
[2014-12-17 02:15:55.082758] [0x10000000] [fatal]   init
```

#### Use dynamic Link still not work, unknown why

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ x.cc  -lsocket  -lnsl -o x -pthread -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lrt
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&) /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
icu::Collator::createInstance(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()   /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
icu::Locale::Locale(icu::Locale const&) /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*) /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
icu::Locale::Locale()               /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
icu::Locale::~Locale()              /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc64-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.2/../../../libboost_regex.so.1.57.0
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*) /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()  /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get() /var/tmp//ccegh2wS.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to x
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You might need to link with `boostlog_setup` as well.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg,  it still doesn't work:(

Comment: Also  try using `nm -A libboost_* | grep mt_posix` on the resulting library and checking the symbols to see if they're there. Depending on the mt, st, or v2s or v2, you should be able to then deduce which flags are necessary to build in a compatible fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the compiler does choose mt or st based on the `-pthread` flag. As far as dynamic linking goes, when boost was built, you may have done something like:

`./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=log,program_options,regex,filesystem,system,thread --prefix=/opt/csw/
./b2 link=static define="_XOPEN_SOURCE=600" install`

`link=static` to build only static libraries.

For me this seems to affect whether or not your library has v2s or v2. See:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html

Comment: I wish I found this thread sooner, it's been such a PITA on Solaris digging through posts etc to get it to work. I managed to get this running as well on on 1_59_0 as well.

Comment: Also FYI, as of 1_55_0, the _XOPEN_SOURCE=600 is required to get through compiling the logger or you get preprocessor errors.